# Sorting in DataGridView using DataSource property

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a `List` that contains items, for example:

```
1) https:\\10.12.23\\
2) https:\\12.23.12.25\\
3) https:\\localhost\
4) https:\\12.25.12.2\\
5) https:\\12.36.12.22\\
6) https:\\12.88.12.32\\
```

The `List` is bound to a `DataGridView` as follows:

```
MyDataGridView.DataSource = MyList;
```

I want the item `https:\\localhost\` to be on the top. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sort the list before binding it.

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();

List<string> sortedItems = items
    .OrderByDescending<string, string>(i => i)
    .ToList<string>();
```

This is a very basic example.  There is also an `OrderBy` method to sort ascending.  If you had an object list, you would change the return type of the (i => i) to have the property for example date would look like `.OrderByDescending<string, DateTime>(i => i.SomeDate)`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to keep https://localhost/ at the top, then:

```
int i = items.FindIndex(delegate(string s) { return s.Contains("localhost"); });
if (i > -1) {
  string localhost = items[i];
  items.RemoveAt(i);
  items.Insert(0, localhost);
}
MyDataGridView.DataSource = items;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If instead you wanted to specifically float localhost to the top, but sort the rest ascending, you could instead do something like this:

```
MyDataGridView.DataSource = MyList
    .OrderByDescending(i => i.Contains("://localhost/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .ThenBy(i => i)
    .ToList();
```

Note that the generic types on the methods can usually be inferred by the compiler.